# PHP multidimensional array returns empty subarrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, opencart

I'm using php to pull data from a mysql database using an array of values.

My initial array, $models, is a list of part numbers that looks like this:

```
 Array ( 
         [0] => AB-1 
         [1] => AB-2 
         [2] => BCA-2 
         [3] => DE3 
 )
```

Here's the foreach that sets up my data so I can display the products on my template page:

```
$products = array();

 foreach ($models as $key => $prod_num) {
        $product_info = $this->model_extension_news->getModelInfo($prod_num);
        if ($product_info['image']) {
                            $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_wishlist_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_wishlist_height'));
                        } else {
                            $image = false;
                        }

                        if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
                            $stock = $product_info['stock_status'];
                        } elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
                            $stock = $product_info['quantity'];
                        } else {
                            $stock = $this->language->get('text_instock');
                        }

                        if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                            $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                        } else {
                            $price = false;
                        }
            $products[] = array(
                            'product_id' => $product_info['product_id'],
                            'thumb'      => $image,
                            'name'       => $product_info['name'],
                            'model'      => $product_info['model'],
                            'stock'      => $stock,
                            'price'      => $price,     
                            'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product_info['product_id']),

                        );

                }
```

I access the database to find the $product_id and other info from a function called getModelInfo() (I'm using the opencart framework):

```
public function getModelInfo($prod_num){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT p.product_id, pd.name AS name, p.model AS model, p.image, p.price, p.quantity FROM " . DB_PREFIX ."product p LEFT JOIN ".DB_PREFIX."product_description pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id WHERE p.model = '".$prod_num."'");
         return array(
                        'product_id'       => $query->row['product_id'],
                        'name'             => $query->row['name'],
                        'model'            => $prod_num,
                        'image'            => $query->row['image'],
                        'price'            => $query->row['price'],
                        'quantity'         => $query->row['quantity'],
                         );
    }
```

The problem is that my return array is incomplete. The first result is filled out, but the additional results return blank info from the database. I know there is data for each of these products in the database... and I can't understand why no data is shown for the last 3 products in my $products array:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
              [product_id] => 18713 
              [thumb] => http://www.website.com/image/AB-1.jpg 
              [name] => AB-1 FULL 
              [model] => AB-1 
              [stock] => 79 
              [price] => $168.00 
              [href] => http://www.website.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=18713 
        ) 
         [1] => Array ( 
               [product_id] => 
               [thumb] => 
               [name] => 
               [model] => AB-2 
               [stock] => 
               [price] => 0 
               [href] => http://www.website.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id= 
        ) 
         [2] => Array ( 
               [product_id] => 
               [thumb] => 
               [name] => 
               [model] => BCA-2
               [stock] => 
               [price] => 0 
               [href] => http://www.website.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id= 
        ) 
         [3] => Array ( 
               [product_id] => 
               [thumb] => 
               [name] => 
               [model] => DE-3 
               [stock] => 
               [price] => 0 
               [href] => http://www.website.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id= 
        ) 
)
```

What am I missing here? Am I doing something wrong in the foreach? Is there some other way to set up $products? I just can't seem to see what is going wrong with this code. Any help (or redirection to a solved version of this issue) is appreciated!

Comment: You are doing a Left Join which means the results have to satisfy a single table. Try with a full JOIN (both tables) and  then a RIGHT JOIN (single table but the other side).

Comment: I just tried it with JOIN, INNER JOIN, and RIGHT JOIN. There was no difference in returned results...

Comment: before first foreach define $products = array(); and then try?

Comment: I have that in there on my complete function. (I didn't post the entire thing because it has a bunch of irrelevant stuff). I'll add it to the snippet.

Comment: Check your data for consistent values . You are making join on  product id ON p.product_id = pd.product_id WHERE p.model = '".$prod_num."'" which means all products have to have id's and models no field can be empty for the called query fields

Comment: Iteration error is a likely cause.  The first time through the loop, variable values are set.  The second time through the loop, only the model number is set to a new value before testing.  After the tests are done, in the if/elses, then the variables would have been reset to new values.  The clue is that only the first one gets done.  The loop needs to be primed on the second pass to react to the tests.

Comment: @Carl McDade I went ahead and checked each product; all called fields are filled on each product.

Comment: Why is there a comma after quantity in the return array?  Same-same for href in the other array.

Comment: @gladiola : what do you mean by "primed"? I understand you're talking about making sure the additional values are being run, but how do I force this without using an index? Can you point me to an explanation?

Comment: @gladiola : I don't know, those extra commas are common on opencart scripts. They don't make a difference. I've removed them just now to test, and it didn't change anything.

Comment: How about a space after the second " following the spaghetti of the DB Prefix?  The only part of the code that seems to be making it through is the  part that is not set by the query.  So, maybe something's wrong with it.  OIN ".DB_PREFIX."produc to OIN ".DB_PREFIX." produc _PREFIX."product_des to _PREFIX." product_des

Comment: @gladiola: No, I can't add a space, because the prefix is a part of the table name i.e.: opencart_product. DB_PREFIX is a variable set in the config file.

Comment: @Captain Crunch : $products[] is set up inside the foreach loop... The final $products array shows me an entry for each product in $models, I'm just somehow missing the information that's coming directly from the db.

Comment: var_dump that  $product_info at the top of the loop and see what you get.  If it's not loading and reloading, you'll see right away.  It may be helpful in your troubleshooting not to reuse variable names for similar purposes; like, $query could be $query and $results, $prodnum could be $prodnumIn in the function, etc.  It could cut down on scope problems.  That's all I've really got for you.  Happy hunting.

Comment: @gladiola: var_dump shows that it's iterating through each product, but it is showing NULL results for the final 3 products. Ex: array(6) { ["product_id"]=> NULL ["name"]=> NULL ["model"]=> string(5) "BCA-2" ["image"]=> NULL ["price"]=> NULL ["quantity"]=> NULL }

Comment: var dump inside the function, after the query but before the array is assigned and returned.  That should clue you in on what's coming back.  I apologize for providing such small and tedious advice; but, really, this is how I end up proofing code often.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly where I put it - I definitely know each product is getting sent through to getModelInfo(). I wouldn't be able to see $products[1]['model'] if I wasn't receiving that return array. No worries about the minutiae, I do the same thing; I know I must be missing something glaringly obvious, and I appreciate the extra set of eyes!

Comment: OK.  The first time I meant put the var_dump inside the foreach loop.  I thought put it before if ($product_info['image']) {

Comment: Are you freeing up the result set?  From query to query, are you allowing php to query again, fresh?  Like in patterns like:  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php  I'm not familiar with the way you've used your query above.  I usually use a five step process with mysqli type commands.

Comment: I'll check back later.  Let us know if you find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

is there a possibility you lacking a product description for some of your products? in that case, your "LEFT JOIN" won't return you a result for that product. you need to use: "LEFT OUTER JOIN" (follow this link to understand what it does: [SQL LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)) instead.

iv'e added it in your query:

```
$query = $this->db->query("
SELECT 
    p.product_id, pd.name AS name, p.model AS model, p.image, p.price, p.quantity 

FROM 
    " . DB_PREFIX ."product p 

LEFT JOIN
    ".DB_PREFIX."product_description pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id WHERE p.model = '".$prod_num."'");
```

Comment: All of the products have names & descriptions.  

I'm already using LEFT JOIN. I just put in LEFT OUTER JOIN and it didn't made a difference. 

I tested JOIN, INNER JOIN, and RIGHT JOIN as well, and nothing changed. I tried FULL OUTER, too, just to see what happened - that broke everything.